# How to make a new environment based on a given table

Tags: tables, environments

I want to make an environment `obj` (numbered by chapter) such that the command

```
\begin{obj}{Text 1}
  Text 2
\end{obj}
```

generates the following (assuming that this is the first `obj` environment in chapter 1) :

```
\documentclass{report}   

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{/}{!{\textcolor{myblue}{\vrule width 1.5pt}}}
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\arrayrulecolor{myblue}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{0.25in} p{0.05in} X }
  \textcolor{myblue}{\textbf{1.1}} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\textcolor{myblue}{Text 1}} \\
  \Cline{2.5pt}{1-3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{/p{0.05in}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\vspace{0.0pt}
  Text 2} \\
  \Cline{1.5pt}{2-3}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly easier to do this as a macro:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{/}{!{\textcolor{myblue}{\vrule width 1.5pt}}}
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\arrayrulecolor{myblue}


\newcounter{object}[chapter]
\renewcommand\theobject{\thechapter.\arabic{object}}
\newcommand\obj[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{object}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{0.25in} p{0.05in} X }
    \textcolor{myblue}{\textbf{\theobject}} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}} \\
    \Cline{2.5pt}{1-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{/p{0.05in}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\vspace{0.0pt}
    #2} \\
    \Cline{1.5pt}{2-3}
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}
```

}

```
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}
\obj{Text 1}{Text 2}

\end{document}
```

will produce (for the second chapter):

[image]

Comment: I agree, the macro is better. Can you make it automatically numbered within each chapter like a theorem ? I don't want all of them to be numbered "1.1". That would defeat the point of the macro.

Comment: Also I get a lot of error messages on line 23 `\endtabularx\end{center}}` including "missing `\begin{document}`". It doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @simplejack Sorry, missed  the counter requirement. Not sure why there was a compilation error before either...both fixed now.